# Why are some of my dictionary keys and values disappearing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

This is my code:

```
listy = [[(100, 1), (90, 2), (90, 2), (80, 3), (70, 4)], [(100, 1), (90, 2), (90, 2), (80, 3), (80, 3)]]
track = [dict(x) for x in listy] 
print(track)
```

I have a nested list of tuples and I am turning them to a dictionary inside a list but the problem is some of the keys and values are disappearing after being changed from tuples. The output is coming out like this:

```
[{100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3, 70: 4}, {100: 1, 90: 2, 80: 3}]
```

Instead, the output should have been like this:

```
[{100:1, 90:2, 90:2, 80:3, 70:4},{100:1, 90:2, 90:2, 80:3, 80:3}]
```

Why is my code giving the wrong output, and what might be the possible solution to the problem. I am using Python 3.x

Comment: The duplicate key is not allowed, isn't it?

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in dictionaries.

Comment: But then, is there a solution to it?

Comment: That depends what the problem is that you're trying to solve. Why do you think you need them to be a dict?

Comment: You don't use a dictionary, use different keys or make the values a list.

Comment: @PeterGibson I need it to be a dictionary, because after I will use a second list to search for the keys. For example: the second list is [100,90]. So I will use it find all the values of 100s and 90s by using the dictionary.

Comment: @Mahir. If you allow duplicate keys, you need a different data structure

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. This may be a beginner question, but it's pretty clear and shows some thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python doesn't allow duplicate keys in dictionaries. In something similar to your example:

```
>>> d={100:1, 90:2, 90:3, 80:3, 70:4}
>>> d[90]
3
```

If it allowed duplicate keys, theres no way for it to know whether to return `2` or `3` for `90`.

You could use `collections.Counter`, if you want to keep track of the count of tuples:

```
from collections import Counter
listy = [[(100, 1), (90, 2), (90, 2), (80, 3), (70, 4)], [(100, 1), (90, 2), (90, 2), (80, 3), (80, 3)]]
count = [Counter(x) for x in listy]
print(count)
```

Which gives the output:

`[Counter({(90, 2): 2, (100, 1): 1, (80, 3): 1, (70, 4): 1}), Counter({(90, 2): 2, (80, 3): 2, (100, 1): 1})]`

Or, if all you want to do is relate the keys to values, you can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

listy = [
    [(100, 1), (90, 2), (90, 2), (80, 3), (70, 4)],
    [(100, 1), (90, 2), (90, 2), (80, 3), (80, 3)],
]


update_lists = []
for l in listy:
    # if a key is not found, automatically create a list
    u = defaultdict(list)
    for (k, v) in l:
        u[k].append(v)
    update_lists.append(u)

print(update_lists)
```

Which gives the following output:

`[defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {100: [1], 90: [2, 2], 80: [3], 70: [4]}), defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {100: [1], 90: [2, 2], 80: [3, 3]})]`

Answer (score 0):

Values appear to disappear because you try to create dict with duplicate keys:

```
data = [(1, 'one'), (1, 'two'), (2, 'three')]
dictionary = dict(data)
```

Will result in:

```
{1: 'one', 2: 'three'}
```

Python dictionaries doesn't support duplicate keys.

@Mahir
You can associate multiple values to single key in dictionary doing something like this

```
multi_value_dict = {}
multi_value_dict.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
```